# When obfuscating with ProGuard, does -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable make the resulting apk easier to reverse engineer?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I find myself needing more detail in my reported stack traces, but I'm concerned that by including the extra data (by using -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable) I'm making my app even easier to reverse engineer.  Is this the case, and if so, by how much?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[ProGuard manual > Examples > Producing useful obfuscated stack traces](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace)

The SourceFile attribute is required, because Oracle/Sun's Java virtual machine otherwise does not include line numbers in stack traces, which is what you really want (and which is quite harmless on its own). I haven't checked if this is true for Android's Dalvik virtual machine.

As for a solution, ProGuard can keep the SourceFile attribute but replace its contents by a meaningless string of your choice, e.g.

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

The value of the string is not important for interpreting the stack traces. Picking a string like "SourceFile" avoids increasing the class file sizes, because this string is already present by definition.

Comment: @Eric, Why garble class names if your going to keep the source file attribute ? Sure stacktraces will be useless, but isnt that the point of obsfucation ?

Comment: @mP The above configuration keeps the SourceFile attribute, but replaces its contents. The JVM will then print out complete stack traces, but with obfuscated names. These can be useful for debugging the obfuscated application, with the help of the mapping file that ProGuard generates for the developer.

Comment: "and which is quite harmless", how its harmless if anyone can see the actual file name after decompiling ? that makes obfuscating completely useless.

Comment: @xmenW.K. See the comments above -- the actual file name is gone; it is replaced by a meaningless string, e.g. "SourceFile".

Comment: Yes only after using '-renamesourcefileattribute'

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure of what happens but given the source file name contains the actual name of the class, someone could use this to map obfuscated class names into real class names. Given obfsucation already jumbles everything up why keep the source file at all ? Everything should and will still run, the debug details are not required by the runtime so it makes no sense to keep them. The more you remove the better given your goals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use:

```
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-renamesourcefileattribute
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
```

or

```
-renamesourcefileattribute ''
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
```

Just let filename empty  is ok